# could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[com.sweetsoft.SapHealth]

Tags: scala, circe

I have the following code, that does not compile:

```
import java.time.Instant

import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

trait SapHealth {}

case class SapHealthRejected(reason: String) extends SapHealth

case class SapHealthAccepted(sapId: String, requestedAt: Long) extends SapHealth


object SapHealth {

  private val build: SapHealth = SapHealthAccepted(SapmockActor.system.name, Instant.now().getEpochSecond)

  val create: String = build.asJson.noSpaces

  implicit val encodeFieldType: Encoder[SapHealthAccepted] =
    Encoder.forProduct2("sap-id", "requested_at")(SapHealthAccepted.unapply(_).get)

  implicit val decodeFieldType: Decoder[SapHealthAccepted] =
    Decoder.forProduct2("sap-id", "requested_at")(SapHealthAccepted.apply)

}
```

The compiler complains:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[com.sweetsoft.SapHealth]
[error]   val create: String = build.asJson.noSpaces
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've specifically up-cast `build` to `SapHealth`, but you don't provide an `Encoder` instance for `SapHealth` (only `SapHealthAccepted`), and circe-generic can't derive one because you haven't sealed the trait hierarchy.

The most straightforward solution would be to add `sealed`:

```
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

sealed trait SapHealth {}
case class SapHealthRejected(reason: String) extends SapHealth
case class SapHealthAccepted(sapId: String, requestedAt: Long) extends SapHealth

object SapHealth {
  implicit val encodeFieldType: Encoder[SapHealthAccepted] =
    Encoder.forProduct2("sap-id", "requested_at")(SapHealthAccepted.unapply(_).get)

  implicit val decodeFieldType: Decoder[SapHealthAccepted] =
    Decoder.forProduct2("sap-id", "requested_at")(SapHealthAccepted.apply)

  private val build: SapHealth = SapHealthAccepted("foo", 123L)

  val create: String = build.asJson.noSpaces
}
```

Note that you also need to rearrange the definitions to avoid running into null-pointer exceptions because of initialization order (if you put `create` before `encodeFieldType`, the derived `SapHealth` encoder will try to use `encodeFieldType` before it's initialized). With the rearrangement above, this works just fine:

```
scala> SapHealth.create
res2: String = {"SapHealthAccepted":{"sap-id":"foo","requested_at":123}}
```

Note that the derived `SapHealth` encoder is using your custom `SapHealthAccepted` encoder, which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Why does the `sealed` mean?

Comment: The `sealed` makes it impossible to extend `SapHealth` outside of the current compilation unit. The generic derivation in circe-generic relies on Shapeless's generic representation of ADTs, and Shapeless doesn't provide generic representations for unsealed trait hierarchies.

Answer (score 3):

Trait `SapHealth` should be sealed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find this answer helpful—it doesn't address why sealedness would matter in this case, why `encodeFieldType` doesn't kick in, the initialization order problems, etc. Maybe the OP would be able to get to a solution from here, or maybe not, but it's definitely unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: @TravisBrown You just were faster than me. And after your answer I didn't see any reason to update mine. Good luck.

Comment: Don't really get the "here's a placeholder answer while I write a proper one" thing but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for case class you can use deriveEncoder/deriveDecoder. But in case of complex class you should (as I think) specify it for argument's classes.

https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/semiauto-derivation.html

```scala
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._

case class Foo(a: Int, b: String, c: Boolean)

implicit val fooDecoder: Decoder[Foo] = deriveDecoder[Foo]
implicit val fooEncoder: Encoder[Foo] = deriveEncoder[Foo]
```